# Запятая перед "сколько"

Tags: пунктуация

Не могли бы вы подсказать, как правильно пишется данное предложение:

> Я вижу, что(,) сколько людей, столько и мнений!

Нужна ли запятая перед "сколько"? Какое правило это регламентирует?

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать излишние вежливости, задавая вопрос. Если он хороший, вам и так обязательно помогут!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его как принятый (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 2):

**Я вижу, что сколько людей, столько и мнений!**

Это сложное предложение, изъяснительная часть "сколько людей, столько и мнений" составляет единую конструкцию, поэтому запятая после изъяснительного союза ЧТО не ставится.

Правило такое: если перестановка предложений 2 и 3 невозможна, то запятая на стыке союзов (ЧТО и СКОЛЬКО) не ставится.